# Random subsampling of a data.frame and summarize mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, random

In R, I have some ecological data in this form:

```
sample <- seq(1, 20, by=1)

group <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","E","E","E",
          "E","E","E","E","F","F","F")

df <- data.frame(sample, group)
```

Where `sample` is the sample number and `group` is a different taxonomic group associated with each sample

In total, I have 20 samples (in reality more) and I can get the relative frequency of a certain group with:

data.frame(table(group)/length(group))

```
group Freq
1     A 0.15
2     B 0.10
3     C 0.05
4     D 0.05
5     E 0.50
6     F 0.15
```

Now I would like to subsample (10 samples) my data frame for 100 times and get the mean relative frequency of each group together with the standard deviation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
data <- with(
    df,
    proportions(
        replicate(
            100,
            table(
                factor(Group[sample(Sample, 10)], levels = unique(Group))
            )
        ), 2
    )
)
```

to obtain

```
> data
   
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
  A  0.2  0.3  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.2  0.1   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2
  B  0.1  0.2  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
  C  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1
  D  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1
  E  0.4  0.5  0.5  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.6  0.5  0.3   0.5   0.7   0.4   0.7   0.5
  F  0.2  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.3   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1

    [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26]
  A   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.1
  B   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1
  C   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1
  D   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1
  E   0.5   0.6   0.6   0.3   0.5   0.5   0.6   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.5
  F   0.1   0.3   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1

    [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38]
  A   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.0   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.2
  B   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
  C   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0
  D   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1
  E   0.5   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.2   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.6
  F   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.3   0.1

    [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50]
  A   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1
  B   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1
  C   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
  E   0.7   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.5   0.5   0.7   0.8   0.2   0.4   0.4   0.6
  F   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1

    [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62]
  A   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.3   0.0   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2
  B   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.2   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1
  C   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0
  D   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
  E   0.5   0.5   0.6   0.5   0.3   0.4   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.5
  F   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2

    [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74]
  A   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.3   0.1   0.2   0.2
  B   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1
  C   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1
  D   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1
  E   0.6   0.4   0.6   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.5   0.6   0.6   0.4
  F   0.2   0.2   0.0   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1

    [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86]
  A   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.0   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.0   0.1   0.1
  B   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1
  C   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
  D   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0
  E   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.6   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.6
  F   0.2   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.0   0.2   0.3   0.2

    [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98]
  A   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.3   0.3
  B   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.0   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1
  C   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.0
  E   0.7   0.5   0.6   0.5   0.7   0.5   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.6   0.4   0.4
  F   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.0   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2

    [,99] [,100]
  A   0.1    0.2
  B   0.1    0.2
  C   0.0    0.0
  D   0.0    0.1
  E   0.7    0.4
  F   0.1    0.1
```

---

Based on the achieved `data`, you can get `mean` and `sd` by

- `mean` by groups

```
> rowMeans(data)
    A     B     C     D     E     F 
0.167 0.096 0.051 0.056 0.492 0.138
```

- `sd` by groups

```
> apply(data, 1, sd)
         A          B          C          D          E          F
0.08577631 0.07035265 0.05000000 0.05016136 0.12583057 0.07869517
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear, but what about something like this in base R. The idea is to create 100 sample in a list, `lapply()` to each element the relative frequency calculation, and lastly put it in a `data.frame()` to aggregate and calculate `mean()` and `sd()`.

```
# first an empty list
listed <- list()

# now you create a data.frame with all the groups in unique()
unique_groups <- data.frame(group = unique(df$group))

# now let's populate it:
# set seed for sake of reproducibility
set.seed(1234)
for(i in 1:100){
              # sampling
              temp <- df[sample(nrow(df), 10), ]
              # merge with the unique data frame
              temp <- merge(unique_groups, temp, by = 'group', all.x = T)
              # replace NAs with 0s
              temp[is.na(temp)] <- 0
              # put it in list
              listed[[i]] <- temp
 }

# here you apply to each element of the list your frequency calc
listed_freq <- lapply(listed, function(x) data.frame(table(x$group)/length(x$group)) )

# put it as data.frame
df_freq <- do.call(rbind, listed_freq)

# here you aggregate and calculate mean and sd
aggregate(. ~ Var1, data = df_freq, FUN = function(x) c(mn = mean(x), stdev = sd(x) ) )
```

With result:

```
  Var1    Freq.mn Freq.stdev
1    A 0.17333333 0.05958659
2    B 0.15362319 0.05023389
3    C 0.10000000 0.00000000
4    D 0.10000000 0.00000000
5    E 0.47300000 0.11621558
6    F 0.16813187 0.06972824
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was very useful and I've learned a lot from it. The only thing is that the mean and the standard deviation do not consider subsamples where one or more groups are missing (i.e. their relative frequency is 0). I need that both mean and standard deviation are calculated including all the subsamples.

Comment: You're welcome: see edit. We need only a new df with unique groups, and tweak a bit the loop. You can manage it also with functions like `complete()` but imo this is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `tidyverse` (`purrr` and `dplyr`) for a functional approach. Not sure what you want to do with the standard deviation:

```
library(tidyverse)

times <- 100
subpopulation <- 21

sample_summary <- function(time, df_in = df, subpop = subpopulation){

    df_temp <- df_in[sample(1:nrow(df_in), size = subpop, replace = TRUE),]
    df_summary <- df_temp %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(mean_freq = n() / subpop) 
    df_summary$experiment <- time
    
    return(df_summary)
}

1:times %>%
    map_dfr(., sample_summary)
```